# Import data from Excel to Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have some columns in `Sheet 1` in Excel. I need to import the data into Access by matching column headers in both Access & Excel. In the same way, I want to import multiple Excel files into Access appending the data to existing tables according to the columns (fields) in Access.

Is this even possible? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: This question seems more like a "give me code" request than a question.  And in the original version, that's what it clearly was: "Kindly suggest me some codes".  I don't think it should be re-opened now.

Comment: @HansUp I am not disagree that the questioner may have a bad history, I am saying that SO is a wiki, and as a wiki question this is useful. It is a problem that has come up quite a bit recently and this is the shortest question, therefore the most readable, that states the problem. I believe the question should be preserved and it can be preserved as community wiki.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to link the Excel sheet or range:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, _
"Atable", "z:\docs\test.xls", True, "A1:A15"
```

You then have a table that can be manipulated with the usual MS Access SQL.

You can also refer to an Excel sheet - `[Sheet1$]` - or range in a query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( ADate ) 
SELECT SomeDate FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].[Sheet1$a1:a4]
```

Or use a named range, note that Excel 8.0 is also suitable for 2007 type files.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xlsm].[XLTable]
```

Where XLTable is a named range.